# Is it possible to send a signed transaction directly to a TPU using Node.js?

Tags: transactions

I have:

- The bytes of a signed transaction with a recent blockhash, in wire format
- The TPU host/port of the current leader

Is it possible to send the transaction directly to the leader's transaction processing unit (TPU) using Node.js and JavaScript?

I've tried using the following transports:

- `import quic from 'node-quic';` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-quic))
- `import { Client } from 'quic';` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quic))
- `import { createConnection } from 'node:net';` ([link](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netcreateconnectionport-host-connectlistener))

My transaction sender is implemented using code sufficiently similar to this:

```
const client = new Client();
await client.connect(port, host);
client.on("connection", (stream) => {
  stream.write(txBytes, () => {
    console.log("sent transaction");
  });
});
```

What I observe is the `connect` phase hang forever, then eventually result in `ECONNREFUSED` or `ETIMEDOUT`.

What did I get wrong?

- I'm supposed to be doing some sort of key exchange before sending data?
- My client IP is not on some allowlist?
- Wrong port? (I read something about [`QUIC_PORT_OFFSET`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/9a520fd5b42bafefa4815afe3e5390b4ea7482ca/sdk/src/quic.rs#L5) and tried adding `6` to the port number, but to no avail)
- This just isn't possible anymore?
- Something else?