Got "Peer closed with transport code 306" when trying to send transaction via QUIC in node.js
I would love to make https://github.com/lmvdz/tpu-client/ work with QUIC.

https://github.com/lmvdz/tpu-client/pull/6

So I'm basically trying to send a transaction via QUIC in node.js
But here's the code, that seems to establish somewhat of a connection, then always fails with Peer closed with transport code 306
import {QUICClient} from "@matrixai/quic";
import * as peculiarWebcrypto from '@peculiar/webcrypto';

const webcrypto = new peculiarWebcrypto.Crypto();

async function randomBytes(data: ArrayBuffer) {
    webcrypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(data));
}

const client = await QUICClient.createQUICClient({
  host: HOST_IP,
  port: parseInt(PORT),
  config: {
      verifyPeer: false,
  },
  crypto: {
      ops: {
          randomBytes
      },
  },
})

const clientStream = client.connection.newStream();
const writer = clientStream.writable.getWriter()
await writer.write(BUFFER);
await writer.close();

providing client RSA certificates (as suggested here https://github.com/MatrixAI/js-quic/issues/98)  doesn't seem to change anything...
Any ideas on why this is failing everytime?
extended error message:
ErrorQUICConnectionPeerTLS: Peer closed with transport code 306
    at constructor_.send [...]/node_modules/@matrixai/quic/src/QUICConnection.ts:947:23)
    at constructor_.send ([...]/node_modules/@matrixai/async-init/src/StartStop.ts:174:20)
    at [...]/node_modules/@matrixai/quic/src/QUICConnection.ts:833:18
    at [...]/node_modules/@matrixai/async-locks/src/Lock.ts:57:63
    at withF ([...]/node_modules/@matrixai/resources/src/utils.ts:24:18)
    at async constructor_.recv ([...]/node_modules/@matrixai/quic/src/QUICConnection.ts:749:5)
    at async Socket.handleSocketMessage ([...]/node_modules/@matrixai/quic/src/QUICSocket.ts:119:7) {
  data: {
    isApp: false,
    errorCode: 306,
    // decodes to "received corrupt message of type InvalidServerName"
    reason: Uint8Array(50) [
      114, 101,  99, 101, 105, 118, 101, 100,  32,
       99, 111, 114, 114, 117, 112, 116,  32, 109,
      101, 115, 115,  97, 103, 101,  32, 111, 102,
       32, 116, 121, 112, 101,  32,  73, 110, 118,
       97, 108, 105, 100,  83, 101, 114, 118, 101,
      114,  78,  97, 109, 101
    ]
  },
  cause: undefined,
  timestamp: 2024-04-09T07:03:42.048Z
}


This is a hard problem unfortunately because of how much more complicated QUIC is compared to simple UDP packets. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9579/is-it-possible-to-send-a-signed-transaction-directly-to-a-tpu-using-node-js has also looked into this, with no luck just yet. This would be great if you can implement it though!

cheers, yes saw your question while trying to read about that topic...
how did you retrieve the addresses in the first place.
because I think those are not just different ports but also IP addresses.
I found out that the the ContactInfo objects retrieved via connection.getClusterNodes() have an undocumented property called tpuQuic...

@JonC  - don't have enough rep left to comment on your question...

Yeah exactly you'll need to send the packets to the TPU port, which only supports QUIC now. You might need to setup a new repo to do this work, since I haven't found any actively maintained libraries in node unfortunately
