How to send transactions directly to tpu
How can i send transactions directly to tpu in node js? i am using solana/web3 and send swap transactions to raydium amm pools
I tries this library https://github.com/lmvdz/tpu-client but the speed left the same

There are currently no JS clients that can interact with the TPU unfortunately, because of the difficulty of implementing a QUIC client. https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9579/is-it-possible-to-send-a-signed-transaction-directly-to-a-tpu-using-node-js has tried
